# Undo Changes Made in ISLR Dataset in R

Tags: r

How do I restore an R package dataframe into its original condition after making changes to it? I recently installed an R package called 'ISLR,' which contains a dataframe called 'Carseats' featuring 12 columns of variables. I removed a column using Carseats <- Carseats[,-1], but I would like the column back into the dataframe.

I have tried the following actions to put it back to no avail:

1. I tried cmd + z to undo steps
2. I tried reinstalling R package ISLR, hoping that the dataframe would be restored.

Any input would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You've edited the Carseats object stored in your environment, not the object that comes with the ISLR package. In RStudio, just use broom to clear objects from your workspace & Carseats wlil go back to the object from ISLR library.